# grep last match from a list of files

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

i have many files under the same folder:

```
uut01_010203030.txt
uut02_020038300.txt
uut03_202002003.txt
```

I can grep the last occurrence individually:

```
tac uut01_*.txt | grep -m 1 'some_pattern'
```

I can feed the file to grep the pattern of first occurrence in the file:

```
ls uut*.txt | xargs grep -m 1 'some_pattern'
```

However, I can't really combine the tac and grep together, the following command gives me error:

```
ls uut*.txt | xargs tac | grep -m 1 'some_pattern'
xargs: tac: terminated by signal 13
```

What can I do to get around this?

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: So many options....how about `for file in uut*.txt; do ...` or `ls uut*.txt | xargs -L 1 sh -c 'tac "$0" | grep ...' `

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tail -n +1 file*
==> file1 <==
1
2
3

==> file2 <==
1
2
3
4
5

==> file3 <==
1
2
3
4

$ grep -H '.' file* | tac | awk -F':' '!seen[$1]++'
file3:4
file2:5
file1:3

$ awk '/./{hits[FILENAME]=$0} END{for (f in hits) print f, hits[f]}' file*
file1 3
file2 5
file3 4
```

Answer (score -1):

yeah, i fond the following command works great:

```
for f in $(find . -name "uut*"); do tac $f | grep -m 1 'some_pattern'; done
```

Comment: Ack!  Don't do that.  Instead use -exec and do something like `find . -name 'uut*' -exec sh -c 'grep "foo" $1 | sed -n "\$p"' _ {} \;`

Comment: what is the reason to use -exec? And why is it bad to use for loop?